# Highcharts Zoom Causes Chart to Disappear

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I have this jsFiddle to illustrate the problem. When I zoom, no matter how much or how little, the chart goes blank, until I reset the zoom.

http://jsfiddle.net/tlbaxter99/vq0wL9de/

When you zoom in on the chart, it goes away and you need to reset the zoom.

Since Stackoverflow requires postings with links to jsFiddles to contain code, here's some code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello StackOverflow!");
```

Comment: If you open your console on the fiddle you'll see that you have 2109 error messages specifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yep -- I noticed I was getting Highcharts error #15. I needed to sort the data! Now it works like a charm.